# Setting up an avatar on android app

Tags: java, android, android-camera, avatar

I'm wanting to let the user create an avatar (profile picture if you like) when they set up their user info.  I've created a method for a single click/touch which would ask the user to take a picture and one for a long click which would ask the user to choose a picture from their gallery.

Below are my methods from the class file:

```
public void onLaunchCamera(View v) {

    avatarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String strAvatarPrompt = "Take your picture to store as your avatar!";
            Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pictureIntent, strAvatarPrompt), TAKE_AVATAR_CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    avatarButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            String strAvatarPrompt = "Choose a picture to use as your avatar!";
            Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            pickPhoto.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pickPhoto, strAvatarPrompt), TAKE_AVATAR_GALLERY_REQUEST);
            return true;
        }
    });
    }
```

And below is the XML associated with the ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton_Avatar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/avatar_size"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/avatar_size"
            android:onClick="onLaunchCamera"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar"></ImageButton>
```

All it does is crash when I click on the ImageButton and I have no idea why.  Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:  Adding the logcat below (Sorry about the formatting.  Couldn't work out how to get it all sorted properly:

```
[ 04-12 18:32:50.989  5901: 5901 D/         ]
HostConnection::get() New     Host Connection established 0xb8a44530, tid 5901
04-12 18:32:51.039 5901-5901/cct.mad.lab D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
04-12 18:32:55.739 5901-5901/cct.mad.lab V/RenderScript: 0xb8c53300     Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
04-12 18:32:57.389 5901-5901/cct.mad.lab D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-12 18:32:57.389 5901-5901/cct.mad.lab W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d2db20)
04-12 18:32:57.399 5901-5901/cct.mad.lab E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: cct.mad.lab,     PID: 5901                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
                                                           at   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                           at  android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                            at a   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                           at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                           at cct.mad.lab.SettingsActivity.onLaunchCamera(SettingsActivity.java:201)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                           at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818) 
                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The logcat should give you the idea *why it crashes*, please add it

Comment: I'm having trouble with the logcat in that nothing has changed on their since the 31st of March.  I'm running the app in debug mode but getting nothing in logcat

Comment: Got the logcat.  I'll add it above

Comment: I'm not that great at reading what the logcat is telling me to be honest

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might not have defined avatarButton, if you follow the Caused By path on the LogCat you see the bottom one is a NullPointerException.

Since I can't see the line numbers, the issue is happening on line 201--the only obvious null pointer I see in your code is avatarButton.

Based on what you want to do, you'll want to go about this a bit differently.

Remove the android:onClick="onLaunchCamera" from the XML.

in your onCreate() after you set the content view add the following:

```
View avatarButton = findViewById(R.id.ImageButton_Avatar);

avatarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String strAvatarPrompt = "Take your picture to store as your avatar!";
        Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pictureIntent, strAvatarPrompt), TAKE_AVATAR_CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }
});

avatarButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        String strAvatarPrompt = "Choose a picture to use as your avatar!";
        Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        pickPhoto.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pickPhoto, strAvatarPrompt), TAKE_AVATAR_GALLERY_REQUEST);
        return true;
    }
});
```

This allows you to set both a click and a longClick listener with more control. The way you had it, you were never really defining the onClick or onLongClick until you clicked on them the first time.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I can see where you're coming from.  However, when entering the View avatarButton, etc... I'm getting the error "Variable 'avatarButton' is already defined in the scope"

Comment: I've just realised avatarButton is defined as an ImageButton by this line in the method initAvatar():     ImageButton avatarButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton_Avatar);

Comment: I've actually worked it out myself.  It actually worked with the 'onLaunchCamera' as the onClick in the XML combined with your line of  
:

View avatarButton = findViewById(R.id.ImageButton_Avatar);